# How to list threads when debugging in Visual Studio Express 2010

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-express

I am trying to track down the reason why my WPF application is not ending cleanly while debugging. By 'cleanly' I mean that all the windows are closed, I can see various messages in the Output window showing that the app has ended but the process is still active and the 'Stop' button in the debugger is still active.

I call the `Shutdown()` method but something is stopping the application from ending. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the ethernet connection to an IO device but cannot see what I am doing wrong. (When I comment out the call to connect the device the app can exit cleanly)

I was wondering if VSE 2010 can list all active threads as this might give a clue as to what is still 'alive' after the main program ends. Or is there an external tool that might help here?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the [Visual Studio `Threads` window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f.aspx) to see which threads are still active. I'm not entirely sure this window is available in the Express edition (the documentation doesn't mention such a limitation), but should you not have it, then you can also [use WinDbg to list all threads](http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#12_thread). WinDbg is part of [the debugging tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx). You might need to install the latest version of the Windows SDK to get it.

Comment: Not able to open the `Threads` window - the item is greyed. Guess it is an Express limitation

Comment: Then WinDbg is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Use the debugger first.  Debug + Break All, Debug + Windows + Threads to see what threads are still running.  You can double-click one and use Debug + Windows + Call Stack to see what it is doing.  The typical case is a thread you started but forgot to tell to terminate.  The Thread.IsBackground property is a way to let the CLR abort a thread automatically for you.

Technically it is possible to have a problem with a device that prevents a process from shutting down.  The Threads window would then typically show only one thread with an otherwise impenetrable stack trace.  If you use Task Manager, Processes tab, View + Select Columns, tick Handles, then you may see only one handle still in use.  The diagnostic then is that you have a lousy device driver on your machine that doesn't properly support I/O cancellation.  Which could leave a kernel thread running that doesn't quit, preventing the process from terminating.  Very unusual, look for the reasons given in the first paragraph first.